# Use Math functions in Angular and cast number to integer

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I have the following Angular 7 Typescript class:

```
export class Paging {

  itemCount: number;
  pageCount: number;
  pageNumber: number;
  pageSize: number;    

  constructor(pageNumber: number, pageSize: number, itemCount: number) {

    this.itemCount = itemCount;
    this.pageCount = itemCount > 0 ? (number)Math.ceil(itemCount / pageSize) : 0;
    this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
    this.pageSize = pageSize;

  }

}
```

I have 2 problems:
1. How to import Math functions (at the moment I am getting an error)?
2. How to convert the result of the calculation `Math.ceil(itemCount / pageSize)` to an integer?

Comment: Remove the `(number)` bit and you should be fine. Typescript doesn't have an integer type, only number, but `Math.ceil` will certainly return an integer in the mathematical sense

Comment: 1)U no need to import  math functions in typescript  2)try **parseInt**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Like [user184994](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2780943/user184994) comment, just remove (number)

   ```
   this.pageCount = itemCount > 0 ? Math.ceil(itemCount / pageSize) : 0;
   ```
2. `Math.ceil` returns integers: `number` (The smallest integer greater than or equal to its numeric argument).

If you need convert into numbers:

```
let str2deci = parseInt('123', 10);

let num = Number('456');
```